# Issues importing a csv in R

Tags: r, csv, dataset, read.table

I'm trying to teach myself R (just started). 
I decided to import 2 csv files to practice a join on them.

One file imported just fine, the other one is giving off the following errors:

Here is the csv file link:

> https://data.world/jonathankkizer/occupation-computerization

I used the following statement

```
occupationforjoin<-read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data
Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

> Warning messages: 
>       1: In read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   :   line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls 
>       2: In read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   :   line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls 
>       3: In read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   :   line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls 
>       4: In read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   :   line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls 
>       5: In read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   :   line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls 
>       6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :   EOF within quoted string 
>       7: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :   embedded nul(s) found in input

I found on StackOverflow that it could be due to encoding, so I used the suggested solution and executed the statement

```
occupationforjoin<-read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data
Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
header=TRUE, sep=",", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

It gave me a different error message:

> Error in read.table("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data
>   Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv",
>   : 
>         more columns than column names

I also tried using the read.csv function to no avail.

How do I fix this problem and import the data set successfully? None of the solutions (e.g., using "skipNul = TRUE", "comment.char="" " parameters) that I found online helped.

**UPD:
Here's the paste of the data set if you don't want to download the csv file from the data world:**
https://pastebin.com/SPEtWT6f

Comment: more cols than tablenamses often means there is an extra comma floating around making it look like 1 columns is actually 2. Can you check for that?

Comment: I've added a link to paste bin in addition to the link to the actual csv file.

I couldn't find any rogue commas, but I've literally just started learning R and might be missing something. I'm at the "Hello world" stage with R, so to speak.

Would you kindly take a look please?

Comment: the separation isn't a comma so save it as a txt file and use: `read.csv("document.txt", header=T, sep="\t")` I also had to indent the first column heading with a tab (which is the delieter)

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls

Comment: 5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input

Comment: I said use read.csv not read.table

Comment: I DID use read.csv
Here how it looks:

occupationforjoin<-read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/OccComp - for Excel.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
...

*********

Comment: Well it worked for me, so I'm not sure what you're doing soz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
I was going nuts; even my instructor didn't know how to fix it!

This statement works:

```
o<-read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/Occ.txt", header=T, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

Like I said in my original question: I tried using **fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"** and it didn't help. After asking the question, I tried using **sep="\t"**, and it didn't help. But using **both** of them did the trick!

Comment: Helps a lot! I had been stuck with this for 20 minutes and scrolled through a bunch of answers before I found this one. Made my day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the function of *read_csv()* from the *readr* package.

Answer (score 1):

Use  dataframe = read.csv("name_of_file.csv")

or

dataframe = read.csv(file.choose()).

Hope this will work.

Comment: Didn't work. Here's the error messages:
*************************

dataframe = read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/-=Data Science=-/11-27-2018/jonathankkizer-occupation-computerization/OccComp.csv")
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
...

Comment: 4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input

Comment: And the resulting data frame is garbage -- 1 variable with no data:
********************************
 
1
NA
2
NA
3
NA
4
NA
5
NA
6
NA
7
NA
8
NA
9
NA
10
NA
11
NA
12
NA
...